# Get the last character of a matched string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL table with HTML stored in a field. A part of this HTML needs to be replaced. An example of a value could be this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
...... //more html
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ...... />
```

Now, using this query:

```
SELECT [Id_Of_Content], 
PATINDEX('<!DOCTYPE%%<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->%<td%>', [Content]) AS StartIndex,
PATINDEX('%<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->%<td%>', [Content]) AS EndIndex
FROM MyTable
```

I get this result:

```
ContentId | StartIndex | EndIndex
1           1            5825
2           1            5819
```

Now, the start index is correct, as the `<!DOCTYPE` element is always at the top of my HTML. But the end index is not what I want it to be: it is always the index of the first character of the string searched for, in this case `<`. I need the index of the `>` character in `<td%>`. How can I get this ?

Comment: You can't, you need to search for whatever follows that string and use that index. The problem here is that you're using tools not really meant to do things like this. The reason why this is not easy to do using SQL is because SQL is the wrong tool. You should do this type of handling in a proper programming language that have better tools, such as full support for regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is for a one time script, so the thought to write something in C# to do it didn't occur to me. I'm going to try finding the starting index of what comes after my desired character intstead.

Answer (score 0):

First find the position where 'main content' starts.
Then find the posision where 'TD' starts.
Then find the position where '>' starts.

The -2 is for the '<' in '!-- Main Content' and 'TD' that are counted twice.

This code works for your example, but may be different from what you expected if you have multiple TD tags (It will use the first).

```
declare @content varchar(max) = '<!DOCTYPE html
...... //more html
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ...... />'

Select EndInSub+TDStartInSub+MainContentStart-2 EndIndex
from(
    select Patindex('%>',[TDSub]) [EndInSub],*
    from( 
        Select SUBSTRING([MainContentSub],[TDStartInSub], [Total Length]) [TDSub],*
        from (
            select PATINDEX('%<td%>',[MainContentSub])[TDStartInSub],*
            from (
                select substring(@content,[MainContentStart],[Total Length]) [MainContentSub],*
                from(
                    select PATINDEX('%<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->%<td%>',@content) [MainContentStart], len(@content) [Total Length]) A)B)C)D)E
```